# Default Value da Role numa dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Tenho no meu index os utilizadores, cada utilizador tem uma Dropdown com as Roles, quando faz o Get não mostrar o valor que está por default na Dropdown

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult IndexGestor(string roles)
        {

            //query entre 2 bases de dados
            var IDsCatequese = db.Catequese.ToList();
            var nomeCatequese = db2.Users.ToList();

            var result = (from o in IDsCatequese
                         join t in nomeCatequese on o.CatequeseID equals t.CatequeseID            
                         //where t.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == t.Id)
                         select new CatequeseUsersViewModel
                         {
                             UserID = t.Id, 
                             Nome = t.Nome,
                             UserName = t.UserName,
                             NomeCatequese = o.NomeCatequese,
                             CatequeseID = o.CatequeseID,
                             //Roles = t.Roles

        }).ToList();


            var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            foreach (var user in result)
            {
                user.Roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.UserID);
                ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db2.Roles, "id", "Name", user.Roles);
            };

            return View(result.ToList());
        }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>                                          <td>                                      
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
    </td>                      
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCatequese)
    </td>
                                                <td>                                      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Roles,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles)
```

}

ViewModel:

```
  public class CatequeseUsersViewModel
    {
        public String UserID { get; set; }
        public String NomeCatequese { get; set; }
        public int CatequeseID { get; set; }
        public String UserName { get; set; }
        public String Paroquia { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public ICollection<String> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

De fato não vai funcionar. Você está escrevendo `ViewBag.Roles` N vezes: uma para cada execução do `foreach`:

```
        foreach (var user in result)
        {
            user.Roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.UserID);
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db2.Roles, "id", "Name", user.Roles);
        };
```

O correto é você escrever a `ViewBag` uma única vez e definir cada `DropDownList` em `View`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>                                      
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>                      
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCatequese)
        </td>
        <td>                                      
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Roles,((IEnumerable<Role>)ViewBag.Roles).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
                Text = option.Name,
                Value = option.Id,
                Selected = (item != null) && (item.RoleId == option.Id)
            }), new { @class = "form-control" })
         </td>
     </tr>
}
```

Comment: O meu Mvc não conhece o argumento "Role" dentro de um IEnumerable. Porque será?

Comment: Alguma coisa está errada aí. Eu não colocaria `public ICollection<String> Roles { get; set; }` dentro do `ViewModel`. Colocaria `public String RoleId { get; set; }`.

Comment: As Roles é uma "ICollection" dos Users, ou se eu modificar as tabelas da minha identity, para ficar um utilizador ser correspondente a uma Role.

Comment: Bom, então a modelagem da *View* está inteira errada mesmo. [Veja os artigos sobre BeginCollectionItem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem) para fazer esta parte.